# Why does this SQL Server UPDATE statement throws a datetime conversion error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some trouble trying to figure it out how to make this update to work.

I think I've done it before without problem, but it seems that it doesn't work now. I don't know what could have changed.

When I execute this, and any similar update statement whith those fields:

```
UPDATE Clientes 
SET CodigoComisionista = 450 
WHERE CodigoEmpresa = 1 
  AND CodigoCliente = '430002801';
```

I get a varchar to datetime conversion error:

> SQL Error (3621): La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo
>   Se terminó la instrucción.
>   Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0,000 sec.

Looking at the column types there I can't see why the `datetime` conversion is thrown. Any thoughts?

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC 
where TABLE_NAME = 'Clientes' and 
(
COLUMN_NAME = 'CodigoEmpresa'
OR COLUMN_NAME = 'CodigoCliente'
OR COLUMN_NAME = 'CodigoComisionista'
)
```

=====>

```
"COLUMN_NAME"           "DATA_TYPE"
"CodigoEmpresa"         "smallint"
"CodigoCliente"         "varchar"
"CodigoComisionista"    "int"
```

Thanks!

---

This is the trigger associated to "Clientes" table:

```
USE [Sage]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Clientes_SyncIU]    Script Date: 15/09/2015 18:11:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Clientes_SyncIU] ON [dbo].[Clientes] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
                AS 
                BEGIN 
                    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

                    DECLARE @AppId AS INT 

                    SET @AppId = 0 

                    SELECT @AppId = sysAppId FROM SpidControlSync 
                    WHERE HostProcess = dbo.host_id_sage() AND sysHostName = dbo.host_name_sage()  
                    IF @AppId < 0 
                        BEGIN 
                            RETURN 
                        END


                        DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
                        DECLARE @idPadre uniqueidentifier
                        DECLARE @linkId uniqueidentifier        
                        DECLARE @oldlinkId uniqueidentifier                         
                        DECLARE @tick int
                        DECLARE @codigoEmpresa int
                        DECLARE @modifiedDate datetime
                        DECLARE @accion VarChar(1)
                        DECLARE @fechaRegistro DATETIME

                        SET @tick = 1 -- by default


                        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Deleted) BEGIN
                            SET @accion = 'U'
                        END ELSE BEGIN
                            SET @accion = 'I'
                        END 

                        DECLARE cur_Inserted CURSOR FOR                         
                        SELECT Inserted.IdCliente, ci.sysLinkId, ci.sysModifiedDate , Inserted.CodigoEmpresa  FROM Inserted LEFT JOIN Clientes_Sync ci on Inserted.IdCliente=ci.sysGuidRegistro  
                        OPEN cur_Inserted
                        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Inserted INTO  @id, @linkId, @modifiedDate, @codigoEmpresa 
                        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
                        BEGIN 
                                                                                                                IF @accion = 'U' AND (@linkId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' OR @linkId IS NULL) BEGIN
                                SET @linkId = @id
                            END
                            -- Call common SYNC Process PROC
                            EXEC  GEN_ProSyncProcess    @appid, 
                                                    @tick output,
                                                    'Clientes',
                                                    @modifiedDate output,
                                                    @fechaRegistro output

                            -- UPDATE SYNC columns on ClientesGCRMIntegration table. 
                            EXEC GEN_ProSyncMetadataInfo @appID,
                                                         @tick,
                                                         @modifiedDate,
                                                         'Clientes',
                                                         'Clientes_Sync',
                                                         @id,
                                                         'SysGuidRegistro',
                                                         @accion,
                                                         @fechaRegistro,@codigoEmpresa,@linkId
                            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_Inserted INTO  @id, @linkId, @modifiedDate, @codigoEmpresa END   
                            CLOSE cur_Inserted
                            DEALLOCATE cur_Inserted 


                END
```

Comment: Probably trigger?

Comment: Maybe is that, and I know nothing about triggers, so I'll have to look into that. I've posted the associated trigger.

Comment: If the trigger calls a bunch of stored procedures that we cannot see, we cannot really help. You should be able to reproduce the error by executing the trigger definition on its own (with fake inserted / deleted tables). Then figure out the stored procedure causing the problem, and look at its body. Keep going at it the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the UPDATE create a duplicate row.

Comment: then the error should be for primary key violation. I think could be trigger as Evk said.

Comment: Error 3621 is : Unable to complete the command. It's not about datetime conversion. Look if you have another error before.